# Can anyone fix my Python unique password generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is it, the problem is it won't change the values of noun and adjective, and prints 0 for noun, 0 for adjective, and a random number between 10 and 99 for number.

```
from random import *
print("I get you password.")
i = 0
noun = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
adjective = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

addNoun = input("Would you like to add a noun? Type yes or no.")
if addNoun == "yes":
  while addNoun == "yes" and i < 10:
    noun[i] = input("Type a third person noun(You're first word). Use no spaces and try to use a mix of lower case and capital letters. ")
    i = i + 1
    addNoun = input("Would you like to add another noun? Type yes or no.")
elif addNoun == "no":
  noun = ["He", "Mr.BossDude", "Dad", "Mom", "Acquaintance"]
else:
  addNoun = input("I said type yes or no.")
  if addNoun == "yes":
    while addNoun == "yes" and i < 10:
      noun[i] = input("Type a third person noun(You're first word). Use no spaces and try to use a mix of lower case and capital letters. ")
      i+=1
      addNoun = input("Would you like to add another noun? Type yes or no.")
  else:
    noun = ["He", "Mr.BossDude", "Dad", "Mom", "Acquaintance"]

addAdjective = input("Would you like to add an adjective or verb? Type yes or no.")
i = 0
if addAdjective == "yes":
  while addAdjective == "yes" and i < 10:
     adjective[i] = input("Type a verb or adjective(You're second word). Use no spaces and try to use a mix of lower case and capital letters. ")
     i+=1
     addAdjective = input("Would you like to add another noun? Type yes or no.")
elif addAdjective == "no":
  adjective = ["IsGud", "Walks", "Sleeps", "Continues", "Falls", "SeesAll"]
else:
  addAdjective = input("I said type yes or no.")
  if addAdjective == "yes":
    while addAdjective == "yes" and i < 10:
      adjective[i] = input("Type a verb or adjective(You're second word). Use no spaces and try to use a mix of lower case and capital letters. ")
      i+=1
      addAdjective = input("Would you like to add another noun? Type yes or no.")
  else:
    adjective = ["IsGud", "Walks", "Sleeps", "Continues", "Falls", "SeesAll"]

number = randint(10, 99)

print("Your password is: " + str(choice(noun)) + str(choice(adjective)) + str(number))
```

I've been trying to fix it but I don't understand why it won't set the list again.

Comment: Try breaking your code up into smaller units and make sure each of those works properly before trying to put together something larger. If you're in doubt, read the documentation for and use `pdb`, the Python debugger, to step through your code one line at a time and try to reason carefully about where your logic is wrong. Otherwise it's hard to help you unless there's a single reproducible problem.

Comment: Probably not much help, but all of this could be refactored into a loop so that all the code repetition is removed. When you find yourself typing similar code over and over where there are just a few differences and the differences are pretty much data, this is a red-flag that you have a function that wants to be written. Once the code was reduced, this would be much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside your array mishandling, you're duplicating both data and logic.  You don't need more code, you need less -- simplify:

```
from random import randint, choice

print("I'll provide you a password.")

nouns = []

while not nouns:
    addNoun = input("Would you like to add a noun? Type yes or no: ").lower()

    if addNoun.startswith("y"):
        while addNoun.startswith("y"):
            nouns.append(input("Type a third person noun (you're first word). Use no spaces and use a mix of lower case and capital letters.\n"))
            addNoun = input("Would you like to add another noun? Type yes or no: ").lower()
    elif addNoun.startswith("n"):
        nouns = ["He", "Mr.BossDude", "Dad", "Mom", "Acquaintance"]
    else:
        print('I said, "type yes or no."')

adjectives = []

while not adjectives:
    addAdjective = input("Would you like to add an adjective or verb? Type yes or no: ").lower()

    if addAdjective.startswith("y"):
        while addAdjective.startswith("y"):
            adjectives.append(input("Type a verb or adjective (you're second word). Use no spaces and use a mix of lower case and capital letters.\n"))
            addAdjective = input("Would you like to add another noun? Type yes or no: ").lower()
    elif addAdjective.startswith("n"):
        adjectives = ["IsGud", "Walks", "Sleeps", "Continues", "Falls", "SeesAll"]
    else:
        print('I said, "type yes or no."')

number = randint(10, 99)

print("Your password is:", choice(nouns) + choice(adjectives) + str(number))
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause is because you initialize your noun and adjective lists with ten zeros, so the function choice(noun) has 90% chance of picking zero.

Instead of initializing the list then filling it, do not declare it and just append your nouns and adjectives using, for instance:

```
curNoun = input( "..." )
noun.append( curNoun )
```